# How to translate "Placeholder" into Portuguese or Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, palavra-para-ideia

For example:

> Use as properties within the options on the Placeholder tab
>
> Go to the Placeholder tab to configure your code

Another example:

> Go to the Placeholder tab, to insert the HTML code attached to a placeholder
>   object.

Comment: Hugo, it's very good that you added use cases, but to make the question better you should explain what a placeholder is.

Comment: One of the translations that use is "marcador".

Answer (score 2):

*Placeholder* is a sign for a space that will be filled with a specific purpose or activity. In Brazilian Portuguese, the usual word for this is `reserva` (and its cognates):

> - Use como propriedades dentro das opções na aba Reservada.
> - Vá à aba Reservada para configurar seu código.

Comment: I've used _Brazilian Portuguese_ just because I'm not sure what's your target audience. Europeans and African Portuguese speakers might have a different word for it.

Comment: You did well, Ramon. In Portugal, I think we use the same word in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Brazil, when a good Portuguese equivalent word is not found for the original word or expression, Brazilians tend to use the original word — as is the case of "self service".

As far as I know, a placeholder is a default text (such as "Enter URL or search term") in web navigators, as you can see in this sample image:

[image: placeholder examples]][1](https://app.knowledgeowl.com/app/image/id/5425aa20fe775ab73e000000/n/2014-09-26_1201.png)

> placeholder
>
> - literal translation: segurador de lugar
> - adaptation: preenchimento.

But I think "preenchimento" is not very appropriate for this use because the placeholder does not actually *fill* (não "preenche") anything, it is just a text for a void space.

So I believe that the best interpretation is "exemplo"(example, sample).
Or, in the case of a picture: "moldura" (frame) or "quadro".

I would translate your sample sentences like this:

> Use como propriedades nas opções da aba de exemplos.
>
> Vá para a aba de exemplos para configurar seu codigo.
>
> Vá para a aba de exemplos, para inserir o código HTML em um objeto de exemplo.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Portuguese SE Jeacom. Poderias traduzir sua resposta para o inglês, visto que a pergunta foi feita neste idioma e, talvez, quem perguntou ainda não compreenda perfeitamente nosso idioma e possa não aproveitar sua boa resposta.

Comment: @gmauch Desculpe, traduzi a resposta o melhor que pude.

Comment: Jeacom, tentei melhorar a tua resposta, espero que gostes das edições. Está à vontade para revertê-las, ou mudá-las! Bem vindo à comunidade. :)